# Download photo without Telegram bot api

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

How can my telegram bot download photos that users sent to it without Telegram bot Api ? (im using pyTelegramBotAPI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) you can use this code:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def handle_photo(message):
    raw = message.photo[2].file_id
    name = raw+".jpg"
    file_info = bot.get_file(raw)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    with open(name,'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your bot use a webhooks, you can use simple php code that will get response  json data and can download the photo that was be uploaded by user. 
That way is will be worked without any lib and extention, just simple php. If you want i can help you with this.